# jasmine unable to test javascript code present inside app/assets/javascripts in ror.Reference Error occurred during $rake jasmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

**Problem description:**

> I setup jasmine for ROR,when i wrote jasmine test-case(i.e 'helloworld.js') which test javascript code(i.e 'hello.js') present inside app/assets/javascripts. When i execute it gives ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined.one more thing when i put "hello.js" file inside spec/javascript/helper/ the test case gets executed without any error.

**ROR project Description:**

> I setup jasmine for ROR(ruby on rails ) project
>       Following is version info of project:
>       Rails -v 3.2
>       jasmine 1.2.1
>       require.js 2.0.6

**ROR project directory structure:**

> blog/
>        app/
>          assets/
>             javascripts/
>                hello.js
>             application.coffee
>        spec/
>          javascripts/
>             helpers/
>             support/
>                jasmine.yml
>             helloworld.js
>          spec_helper.rb
>        /config
>            requirejs.yml
>        Gemfile

```
**Gemfile:**

    group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "capybara"
  gem "launchy"
  gem 'jasmine'
end
```

**hello.js:**

```
function helloWorld() {
    return "Hello world!";
}
```

**helloworld.js**

```
    describe("Hello world", function() {
    it("says hello", function() {
        expect(helloWorld()).toEqual("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

**requirejs.yml:**

> shim:
>   bootstrap-alert:
>               deps: [jquery, bootstrap-transition]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.alert
>           bootstrap-button:
>               deps: [jquery]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.button
>           bootstrap-carousel:
>               deps: [jquery, bootstrap-transition]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.carousel
>           bootstrap-collapse:
>               deps: [jquery, bootstrap-transition]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.collapse
>           bootstrap-dropdown:
>               deps: [jquery]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.dropdown
>           bootstrap-modal:
>               deps: [jquery, bootstrap-transition]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.modal
>           bootstrap-popover:
>               deps: [jquery, bootstrap-tooltip]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.popover
>           bootstrap-scrollspy:
>               deps: [jquery]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.scrollspy
>           bootstrap-tab:
>               deps: [jquery, bootstrap-transition]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.tab
>           bootstrap-tooltip:
>               deps: [jquery, bootstrap-transition]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.tooltip
>           bootstrap-transition:
>               deps: [jquery]
>               exports: jQuery.support.transition
>           bootstrap-typeahead:
>               deps: [jquery]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.typeahead
>           backbone:
>               deps: [underscore, jquery]
>               exports: Backbone
>           underscore:
>               exports: _
>           spin:
>               exports: Spinner
>           jquery.spin:
>               deps: [jquery, spin]
>               exports: jQuery.fn.spin
>           jed:
>               exports: Jed
>           backbone.paginator:
>               deps: [jquery, backbone, underscore]
>               exports: Backbone.Paginator
>       paths:
>           spin: spin-1.2.5
>           jquery.spin: jquery.spin-0.0.1
>           jed: jed-0.5.0beta
>           text: text-2.0.1
>           jade: jade-0.27.0
>           jade.runtime: jade.runtime-0.27.0
>           markdown: markdown-0.4.0
>           backbone.paginator: backbone.paginator-0.1.54.8fcc333d18
>           fs: compat/fs
>           path: compat/path
>           po: plugins/po
>           j: plugins/j
>       stubModules:
>           - text
>           - po
>           - j
>       excludeShallow:
>           - utils/po2json
>           # find vendor/assets/javascripts/jade-0.27.0 -name '*.js' | grep -v runtime | sed -E 's/.*jade[^/]+/(.*).js$/    - jade/\1/'
>           - jade/compiler
>           - jade/doctypes
>           - jade/filters
>           - jade/inline-tags
>           - jade/jade
>           - jade/lexer
>           - jade/nodes/attrs
>           - jade/nodes/block-comment
>           - jade/nodes/block
>           - jade/nodes/case
>           - jade/nodes/code
>           - jade/nodes/comment
>           - jade/nodes/doctype
>           - jade/nodes/each
>           - jade/nodes/filter
>           - jade/nodes/index
>           - jade/nodes/literal
>           - jade/nodes/mixin
>           - jade/nodes/node
>           - jade/nodes/tag
>           - jade/nodes/text
>           - jade/parser
>           - jade/self-closing
>           - jade/utils
>       include:
>           # Forcibly include this for compiled Jade templates to run
>           - jade/runtime
>       modules:
>           - name: application
>           - name: locale/application_es
>             locale: es
>           - name: locale/application_en
>             locale: en
>       wrap: true
>       map:
>           markdown:
>               util: compat/noop
>           jade:
>               sass: compat/noop
>               stylus: compat/noop
>               discount: compat/noop
>               markdown-js: compat/noop
>               marked: compat/noop
>               less: compat/noop
>           utils/jade.trans:
>               jade/jade: jade/runtime

**jasmine.yml**

> ```
> > 
> # src_files
> #
> # Return an array of filepaths relative to src_dir to include before jasmine specs.
> # Default: []
> #
> # EXAMPLE:
> #
> # src_files:
> #   - lib/source1.js
> #   - lib/source2.js
> #   - dist/**/*.js
> #
> src_files:
>   - public/javascripts/prototype.js
>   - public/javascripts/effects.js
>   - public/javascripts/controls.js
>   - public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
>   - public/javascripts/application.js
>   - public/javascripts/**/*.js
>   - app/assets/javascripts/*.js
>
> # stylesheets
> #
> # Return an array of stylesheet filepaths relative to src_dir to include before jasmine specs.
> # Default: []
> #
> # EXAMPLE:
> #
> # stylesheets:
> #   - css/style.css
> #   - stylesheets/*.css
> #
> stylesheets:
>   - stylesheets/**/*.css
>
> # helpers
> #
> # Return an array of filepaths relative to spec_dir to include before jasmine specs.
> # Default: ["helpers/**/*.js"]
> #
> # EXAMPLE:
> #
> # helpers:
> #   - helpers/**/*.js
> #
> helpers:
>   - helpers/**/*.js
>
> # spec_files
> #
> # Return an array of filepaths relative to spec_dir to include.
> # Default: ["**/*[sS]pec.js"]
> #
> # EXAMPLE:
> #
> # spec_files:
> #   - **/*[sS]pec.js
> #
> spec_files:
>   - '**/*[sS]pec.js'
>
> # src_dir
> #
> # Source directory path. Your src_files must be returned relative to this path. Will use root if left blank.
> # Default: project root
> #
> # EXAMPLE:
> #
> # src_dir: public
> #
> src_dir: 
>
> # spec_dir
> #
> # Spec directory path. Your spec_files must be returned relative to this path.
> # Default: spec/javascripts
> #
> # EXAMPLE:
> #
> # spec_dir: spec/javascripts
> #
> spec_dir: spec/javascripts
> ```

**I used following command to setup and run jasmine on ROR**

> > ```
> > $rails g jasmine:install
> > $rake jasmine
> > your tests are here:
> > ```
> >
> > [2012-08-22 21:35:44] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
> >         [2012-08-22 21:35:44] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2012-04-20) [i686-linux]
> >         [2012-08-22 21:35:44] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
> >         [2012-08-22 21:35:44] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3210 port=8888

Answer (score 0):

Try giving app/assets/javascript in src_dir in the jasmine.yml file.